# Django: Non-staff users can login to admin page

Tags: python, django

Python 3.5.1 and Django 1.9

I have created a custom user model in my project:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


# Users
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=50,
    )
    bio = models.TextField()

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True,
                                    verbose_name="Active",
                                    help_text="lorem")
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                   verbose_name="Staff status",
                                   help_text="lorem")
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                       verbose_name="Superuser status",
                                       help_text="lorem")

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, db):
        return True
```

I followed the guide in the official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

I *have* defined AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py

Everything seems to work correctly with the custom user model, execpt...

**Any user can login to the admin interface. This of course is *not* a good thing**

Here is a screenshot of the admin interface when logged in as a *non-admin* user: [image: non-admin login]

And here when logged as an actual admin user [image: admin login]

Note the top right corners. When logged in with a non-admin user, the menu dose not appear. Strange.

Both admin and non-admin users have full access to the admin interface, they can both add, change and delete entries.

Clearly this is a terrible security issue, I don't even know where to start dubugging

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to turn `is_staff` into a property. If you use the built-in User model, Django expects it to be a model field, which means all checks for staff status happen as `if user.is_staff:`, not as `if user.is_staff():`. All you need to do is to include a single line before your `is_staff` method definition:

```
@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin
```

Since Python considers every function object to be True when used in a boolean context, all your users pass the check for `is_staff`.

If you want to know why the admin displays the correct value in the “STAFF STATUS” column, it's because `is_staff` is listed in `list_display` of the default `ModelAdmin` for the user model, and `ModelAdmin` does check items in `list_display` if they're callable or not, and in case they are, it calls them. However, this is only done for the purpose of displaying the value (since `list_display` is a more general mechanism), but not for any actual access control checks.

Comment: This has worked, thanks very much. Thanks for describing what was happening rather than just an answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You musst inheritat from `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin`.

You just included a "bio" field in your User class.
Maybe just extend from `AbstractUser` and not `AbstractBaseUser`. The AbstractUser has most of the important stuff and you can include you bio field there